# Error when trying to inject a named dependency

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have this `AppModule` class that contains a few functions:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
static FirebaseFirestore provideFirebaseFirestore() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("barsRef")
static CollectionReference provideBarsCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("bars");
}
```

Now I want to inject in my repository class an instance of `CollectionReference` but I get the following error:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

This my repository class:

```
@Singleton
class BarsRepository {
    private CollectionReference barsRef;

    @Inject
    BarsRepository(@Named("barsRef") CollectionReference barsRef) {
        this.barsRef = barsRef;
    }

    //Method where I use barsRef
}
```

And this is my `AppComponent` class:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuildersModule.class, BarsViewModelModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

If I remove the `@Named("barsRef")`, it works fine.

Comment: When was the last time you did a clean build?

Comment: @user2836202 I did it right now and I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: At a quick glance, it all seems normal. You could try moving the injection into your module and see if that works.

Comment: @user2836202 I didn't quite understand you. Can you please give me more details. As I said in the last part of my question, if remove the `@Named("barsRef")`, it works fine.

Comment: Instead of the @Inject in your `BarRepository` create a @Provides in the module.
`@Singleton @Provides @Named BarRepository provideBarRepository(@Named("barsRef" CollectionReference ref) { ... }`

Comment: I found the problem. It had in my code another place where I missed to add `@Named("barsRef")`. So it is solved now. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("barsRef")
static CollectionReference provideBarsCollRef(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    return db.collection("bars");
}
```

Remove Singleton from above code. It will work.
The reason why it is happening is because of singleton Scope. Singleton is used to ensure that only one object will be shared within that component.

Comment: I tried using singleton and named annotation. I got error. But when I remove singleton it worked for me.

Comment: I understand but in my case it doesn't work. Beside that, I need a singleton. I need only one object creation.